# How to display GeoJSON from a URL with authentication in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, geojson, json, authentication

I know I can add a GeoJSON url via the Add vector layer ▶ Protocol ▶ GeoJSON. But I have a URL that requires a username/password.  Is there anyway I can provide the username and password for the URL in QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by passing in the username/password in the url: `http://username:password@example.com/` although this method is not recommended for security reasons. Since I am manually verifying Jenkins GeoJson artifacts from a Jenkins server that is internal, I can live with it.